# Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ be any function. If $2|f(x^2)$ then $4|f(x^2)$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

I'm in a math proof class this semester, and one of the students posed this conjecture during our class. I have been thinking about it and worked out a few examples, but I just don't know how to prove the divisibility of general functions.

I think the proof may involve the idea that functions will always output the same parity for a given inputted parity. For example, if the function took in an even number and outputted an odd number, then the function will output an odd number for any given even number. I don't know how to prove this idea either. Please help me formulate these thoughts mathematically.

Comment: Try examples.  Suppose $f(x)$ is the constant function $2$, for example.  For these things, examples are always the way to start.

Comment: Take $f(n)=n+2$ and n=2 as a counter example.

Comment: So the conjecture is wrong!

Comment: What about another conjecture that was posed in class: Let $f$ be a function from the integers to the integers. Then $2|f(x)$ if and only if $2|f(x+2)$.

Comment: As lulu said, if $f(n)=2$ for all $n$, then you notice that for any $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, $2|f(x^2)$, but $4$ does not divide $f(x^2)$ because $2|4$ is false.

Comment: for your other conjecture, try $f(n) = n/2$ if n is multiple of $2$ and $f(n)=3n+1$ otherwise, then 2 divides $f(4)$ but 2 doesnt divide $f(2)$

Comment: in general, if you are allowing *arbitrary* functions $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, you are never going to be able to deduce anything nontrivial about $f(m)$ from $f(n)$ if $m\neq n$

Comment: Piecewise functions will often disprove these types of conjectures. You need more structure than "f is a function from the integers to the integers"

Comment: @LF I see what you did there. Collatz, innit?

Comment: @insipidintegrator yeah buddy!

Comment: @AthelstanCarlton you may find interesting reading about multiplicative functions and totally multiplicative functions, because they make things like $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$ when $m,n$ are coprimes (multiplicative functions) or for all $m,n$ (in case totally multiplicative functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $f(x) = x^2+1$? Then $2|f(x)$ for all odd integers $x$, but $4$ does not divide $f(x)$ for *any* integer $x$.

ETA: As far as the conjecture stated in your comments [that $2$ divides $g(x)$ iff $2|g(x+2)$ where $g$ is a function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$]: It isn't true even if restricted to *polynomial* functions. Let $g(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x}{2}+2$. Then this is integral for all integral $x$. Compare $g(2)$ to $g(4)$ however. So for $x=2$, note that $2$ divides $g(x+2)$ but $2$ does not divide $g(x)$. In fact, for any integer $x$, note that $2$ divides *exactly one of* $g(x),g(x+2)$.